# Android fragment in Flutter plugin using platform views

Tags: android, flutter, android-fragments, flutter-plugin

I am working on developing a flutter plugin for secure video streaming. I use a native android plugin that uses a fragment for playing the video. Going through platform views in flutter. It seems I could only return Android views to a widget using the getView() override method. But I have to use a fragment and I cannot return a fragment to the getView() override method.

Is there anyway I could pass or return a fragment to flutter widget, So that I can use that flutter widget to display the fragment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, Siva
can you help me, please 
if you got a way to do this?